# Using a NULL pointer with OCIAQDeq()

Tags: c, oracle-call-interface, oracle-aq

In [the documentation](http://sqltech.cl/doc/oracle11g/appdev.111/b28395/oci17msc003.htm) for OCIAQDeq() it states:

> The application may choose to pass
>   NULL for payload the first time
>   OCIAQDeq() is called, and let the OCI
>   allocate the memory for the payload.
>   It can then use a pointer to that
>   previously allocated memory in
>   subsequent calls to OCIAQDeq().

Does anyone have an example of how to use this feature? If I pass in `NULL`, where do I subsequently get the pointer from? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of the documentation refers to the `payload` parameter of the function which is a double pointer: `dvoid **` according to the following

- http://files.edin.dk/php/win32/dev/php_build/include/oci805/OCIAP.H

Since it's a double pointer the allocated buffer will be passed back to the caller via the parameter passed in.  For example

```
dvoid* pBuffer = NULL;
OCIAQDec(..., &pBuffer, ...);
```

Because `NULL` is passed the function will allocate a buffer and store it into the `pBuffer` value which can be later re-used

Comment: And then make exactly the same call to OCIAQDeq() again and my data will have appeared at *pBuffer? And this is heap-alloc'd so I could return pBuffer?

Comment: @Gaius that's my understanding from reading the documentation.